# Is there an accepted best practice when it comes out to laying out code?

Tags: sourcecode

Many languages, such as python, have strict rules as to how best to lay out the code. I have looked around but I can't find anything that details this for Latex. For example when looking at creating lists there are a number of ways it could laid out:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Point one
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item SubPoint One
        \item Subpoint Two
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Point two
    \item Point Three
    \item Point four
    \item Point five
\end{enumerate}
```

Or

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Point one
\begin{enumerate}
        \item SubPoint One
        \item Subpoint Two
\end{enumerate}
    \item Point two
    \item Point Three
    \item Point four
    \item Point five
\end{enumerate}
```

or

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Point one
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item SubPoint One
            \item Subpoint Two
        \end{enumerate}
    \item Point two
    \item Point Three
    \item Point four
    \item Point five
\end{enumerate}
```

Is there a best practice for how to lay out Latex code or is it up to the individual to decide?

Comment: Since spaces (and tabs) at the beginning of a line are ignored (except in verbatim environments), it is completely irrelevant whether you use any of those styles. In some cases initial spaces are dangerous. The few cases that come to my mind are `\end{figure}` or `\end{table}` with the `endfloat` package or `\end{frame}` with `beamer` (and a frame declared as `fragile`).

Comment: Thankyou, they do affect readability however. I know python uses white space but other languages don't and still have a 'best practice. Thats interesting with those cases you mentioned, I was not aware of that

Comment: Personally, I don't indent the contents of top level environments; I usually leave a blank line between `\item`s. Sometimes I indent nested environments, but it depends on several factors. I surely *never* rely on automatic indentation offered by editors. However I always indent when *defining* macros or environments. Whether this is a “best practice” I'm not the judge.

Comment: Through your comments and the other question it seems the answer is no, its up to the individual, but there are some cases when it shouldn't be done

Comment: When in doubt, I suppose you can extrapolate from `l3styleguide`, even though that's meant for `expl3` code. I've always used two-space indentation. This question might fare better on [the subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX) :)

Comment: Thanks sean thats exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, I find it strange that LaTeX doesnt have an expanded document of this type